# Do same current formulas apply if a capacitor is added, and vice versa for inductor

Tags: ac, dc, bridge-rectifier, rms

Ok so the title question is a bit misleading but its hard to explain in that small space.
My questions concern themselves with the analyzing of the circuit observed below, however fundamentally speaking my questions are about understanding the concepts.

In my text book (and no I am not looking for numerical answers) it wants to know a plethora of values of the peak to peak kind , rms , average etc...
The issue is that I am given the techniques to find something like voltage ripple peak to peak and output voltage minimum , BUT using a "C filter" with just a resistive load. Then I am given techniques for finding load inductance to limit ripple current BUT the sample problem only has a resistive load.

I am given an LC example but it only works out how to find L1 and C1 which I have worked out and figured them out , but all the other things like ripple voltage , filtered output max, min , form factor and all those other things are only explained for simpler circuits and not this one.

Then I am given this circuit which is not just a "C filter" and not just an "L filter" but an LC filter and not just a resistive load but an RL load.

So my question is do the techniques for finding values still apply , when finding currents do I just look at the inductor techniques and when finding voltages do I just concern myself mostly with the capacitor techniques? Regardless of the fact that they were for simpler circuit with no RL load.

I dont know how to jump form  a simple isolated example using a capacitor or inductor filter with resistive load, to a problem with both LC filter  and an RL load.

And I repeat I have the values for C1 and L1 already they are dependent on Freq. R1 and L2.
Average Output DC Voltage
average output DC current
Output DC power
RMS output Voltage
RMS output current
Rectification Ratio
Form Factor
Ripple Factor
Crest Factor
Transformer Utilization Factor

I am given techniques for some of a the above but the example are always different circuits.
[image: Full bridge Rectifier with LC filter and RL load]

Comment: Ideal application for using a simulator.

Comment: I agree but the simulator will show me output voltage ripple and not the equations of how to go from components values to waveform

Comment: OK, then what did this tell you that is applicable to the posted circuit: *I am given an LC example but it only works out how to find L1 and C1 which I have worked out and figured them out*